# Web Services Testing

Tags: web-services, testing

I know this question was asked million times but I'm gonna ask it again. I've been researching how to test web services for a while and I can't believe that there's pretty much one tool out there: SOAP UI. The other option that you have is creating web services stubs and writing unit tests per each ws stub. 
I can't believe that Microsoft didn't come up with a solid solution for web services testing. So I guess my question: is SOAP UI the only tool for testing multiple web services?

P.S.
I'm also looking for something to integrate with TFS (I know SOAP UI can be integrated with msbuild)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are always options!  Here an old article that could [help out](http://www.infoworld.com/d/architecture/three-open-source-web-service-testing-tools-get-high-marks-995) includes soapUI, Push to test and WebInject.

Looking to shell out dough? You could always use [HP Service Test](http://www8.hp.com/us/en/software/software-solution.html?compURI=tcm:245-937085&pageTitle=service-test-software)

Which do I use?  soapUI of course :) Frankly, it's the most commonly used for a reason.

Answer (score 1):

My alternative to [soapUI](http://www.soapui.org) is [HP Service Test](http://www8.hp.com/us/en/software-solutions/software.html?compURI=1173796).

If I have to build a testing team with testers that are not exposed to web services and SOA in general, then the learning curve and team ramp time associated with HP Service Test is short essentially because of the Canvas based visual drag and drop designer that Service Test boasts.

Perhaps, everything you could do with HP Service Test 11.20 is possible with SOAP UI 4. They both do have striking inherent features that is kind of mutually exclusive between these two.

- If your organization already uses HP's Quality Center, QTP and Load Runner, then for easy effortless mangement of all test cases in your app's boundary it is preferred to have HP Service Test because it integrates with all the aforementioned products.
- With Service Test, I personally like the Canvas designer in HP Service Test and the ability to call .Net assemblies inside of Service Test is just a boon as I am a .Net developer. And the ToolBox has a list of controls that every tester/dveloper needs. And it is just efforless to built a hi-fi test case with Service Test. It is worth the money.
- With soapUI, I like the HTTP Recording (works much like Fiddler) and the Security check options (to name a few, XSLT injection, XSS checks).
- soapUI is omnipresent.

TFS integration, I am not there yet.